# Failed to load image Python extension ... Symbol not found

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I tried to follow the Quickstart Tutorial from the pytorch website and got stuck already at the beginning:

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
```

I got the following error:

```
/project/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torchvision/io/image.py:13: UserWarning: Failed to load image Python extension: 'dlopen(/project/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torchvision/image.so, 0x0006): Symbol not found: __ZN3c106detail19maybe_wrap_dim_slowIxEET_S2_S2_b

Referenced from: <E03EDA44-89AE-3115-9796-62BA9E0E2EDE> /project/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torchvision/image.so

Expected in:     <F2FE5CF8-5B5B-3FAD-ADF8-C77D90F49FC9> /project/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10.dylib

'If you don't plan on using image functionality from `torchvision.io`, you can ignore this warning. Otherwise, there might be something wrong with your environment. Did you have `libjpeg` or `libpng` installed before building `torchvision` from source?
warn(
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: did you install torch and torchvision?

Comment: @MarcoParola: Yes, I did :/

Comment: Are you using windows or linux?